# CSS - How to properly add 3 images in 3 layers

Tags: html, css

I have three layers of images. ( https://jsfiddle.net/zaqu4qja/1/ )

The main problem is that the mountains should be fixed on the bottom but they are floating over the page depending on the screen size.

The second problem is that I'm not the best with css and I would appreciate any advise to improve the css code.

The regarding code for the mountains:

```
#foreground-mountains {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-size: cover;
width: 100vw;
background: url("/img/multiplikationsdreiecke/Vordergrund-Berge.png") no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
#foreground-mountains {
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put this alltogether :

- You can stack multiple images, colors and gradients in the `background`property
- You can define multiple background sizes separated with commas (just keep the declared backgrounds order)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background:
    url("https://s7.postimg.cc/nz903xrjv/Vordergrund-_Berge.png"),
    url("https://s7.postimg.cc/6yq3v96sr/Pyramide.png"),
    url("https://s7.postimg.cc/wu9ueft6z/Hintergrund.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center;
  /* Adjust to your needs */
  background-size: contain, 300px, cover ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason to use multiple divs was to position the inputs inside the pyramid. 
Am I right that I can position the elements only relative to the whole window? If so, how to properly adjust the input properties relative to the pyramid?